# Issues Enabling Google Ads API on Google Cloud Platform Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-ads-api

Every time I try to enable Google Ads API on the google cloud platform i receive the following error:

> API solution not found with service name: googleads.googleapis.com

I've set up an ads manager account under the same email and generated an API access token. I've tried setting it up under different emails and in different browsers and I have even tried using incognito mode to see if that would resolve the issue per the instructions of other threads. I've also created the oauth2 credentials for the project I'm trying to give access to the Google Ads api.

I really just need to enable the Google Ads API. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After paying for Google support, this is what i found:

1. Disable all Google Chrome extensions
2. Start Google Chrome in Incognito Mode
3. Sign into Google Cloud Console and add the api from the api library.

It's that simple.

Answer (score 7):

For me just disabling ad-blocker fixed the issue.